# Is it possible to detect input voltage using only software?

Tags: battery

I'm a newbie to Raspberry Pi's, but one of the things I was thinking about doing is running it off batteries (I see many people do this) - that led me to concerns about shutting down gracefully.  Is there a software only solution that would allow me to detect input voltage?

Comment: See also this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/91433/753) for how to detect undervoltage with software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you'll need some external circuitry to do that, because afaik the raspberry does not provide the battery voltage anywhere in the system: http://raspi.tv/tag/raspberry-pi-monitoring-its-own-battery-voltage

Comment: Apparently this is not true anymore, since newer boards show an thunderbolt icon when underpowered.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Is the "Low Voltage Warning" no longer [asserted on GPIO 35](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=82373)?

Answer (score 12):

`vcgencmd` will show the internal voltages for `core`, `sdram_c`, `sdram_i`, and `sdram_p`:

```
vcgencmd measure_volts core
```

The output will look something like this:

```
volt=1.20V
```

The following shell commands will display all the voltages:

```
for id in core sdram_c sdram_i sdram_p
do
    echo -e "$id:\t$(vcgencmd measure_volts $id)"
done
```

Comment: what should be the voltage for each?

Comment: Unfortunately these are all things inside the 3.3V regulator, meaning not so handy for detecting a gradual decline on the 5V rail.

Answer (score 1):

No, but [MoPi](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hamishcunningham/mopi-mobile-and-24-7-power-for-the-raspberry-pi?token=a93b16b7) is a tidy little board that provides the capability.

Comment: Can you explain how to use MoPi?