# How to check how much battery is left on my Raspberry Pi in the terminal?

Tags: hardware, battery

Is it possible to check how much power is left on the battery powering my Raspberry Pi zero using the terminal?

Comment: What sort of battery pack?  LiPo, for example, might need to be treated differently to NiCad.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't too difficult, although you're going to need a couple of additional components. There's a [good walkthrough](http://raspi.tv/2013/controlled-shutdown-duration-test-of-pi-model-a-with-2-cell-lipo) of the process at raspi.tv. The example there sends an email to a gmail account when the battery voltage dips low enough, but it should be trivial to remove that and add your own code to print to the terminal.

[image: Circuit for Raspberry Pi battery monitoring]

The setup used has the battery simultaneously hooked up to a 5V regulator to feed to Pi, and a voltage divider which feeds the ADC which feeds GPIO pins. A Python script monitors the input from the ADC to determine when the battery voltage drops below a cutoff point.